# How to opt out request body parsing in firebase function? I have to deal with that further in my code instead

Tags: firebase

In request property of my cloud function I get body already parsed by firebase and that lead to fails in my further code. I looking for an option to switch it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't opt out, but you do have access to `req.rawBody` which will give you the untouched body sent over.

Comment: tried it before, but it have no help for me, because when I pass request object to Apollo server further, I think it tries to wait for stream and it also finished and parsed before, so it waits forever and function fails on timeout